# Private base64 encoded key RSA decryption via C#

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

What I am trying to achieve is to create a service that will encrypt and decrypt data using RSA public/private keys. However, the typical implementation in .NET is the one using xml string keys. I have a constraint which makes this not possible - I have pre-made keys in base64.

Somehow, I've achieved encryption using itextsharp library, but the current struggle is to create decrypt functionality. Here you can see some code I've already done:

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string dataToEncrypt = "hello";
        var encryptedWithPublicKey = RSAEncryptionService.EncryptWithPublicKey(dataToEncrypt);
        var decryptWithPrivateKey = RSAEncryptionService.DecryptWithPrivateKey(encryptedWithPublicKey);
    }
}

public static class RSAEncryptionService
{
    private const string PublicKeyBase64 =
        "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCLDfiAR2Z1bHyYT5haopn/KDgKQ3x1wKrVcEx+qBHJxvahh1v1bzQ2flNB/TQMIzy5xiBA5/7vJb8H8RWw5anY6Xr6sRCCSpft6jZ60c1TSxOpCP5OFsG7WJLZPdECk2PBNLQ/SoB7Iw4Ku8WRioYxqWLlY4nXYlaGUnd/2XhpQwIDAQAB";

    private const string PrivateKeyBase64 =
        "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";

    public static string EncryptWithPublicKey(string data)
    {
        var publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(PublicKeyBase64);
        var asymmetricKeyParameter = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(publicKeyBytes);
        var rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters) asymmetricKeyParameter;
        var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters
        {
            Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
        };

        var toEncryptBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
        {
            try
            {
                rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
                var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(toEncryptBytes, true);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
            }
            finally
            {
                rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static string DecryptWithPrivateKey(string base64Encrypted)
    {
        var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(PrivateKeyBase64);
        var asymmetricKeyParameter = PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(privateKeyBytes); // fails here :(
        var rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters) asymmetricKeyParameter;
        var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters
        {
            Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
        };

        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
        {
            try
            {
                rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
                var resultBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encrypted);
                var decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(resultBytes, false);
                var decryptedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
                return decryptedData;
            }
            finally
            {
                rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing the right thing? How to achieve decryption with private base 64 key?

Comment: You've got a PKCS#1 encoded private key, while the import expects a PKCS#8 encoded private key (which *contains* the PKCS#1 private key). Didn't see an example to import it directly and haven't got time to investigate for an answer...

Comment: Do you mean PKCS#1 key is a part of the PKCS#8 key? How can I find rest of the key then? 
Thanks for your answer!